# Using NSDateFormatter on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I am currently using an NSDateFormatter on my application to show the date in the format that i want. My NSDateFormatter looks like this : `[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"];` which would give me dates like : `Sep 02 , 2012 08:30` .
I have 2 questions. i want to show the time in military time how can i do that with the formatter? I know how to show the AM/PM but i would like the time above to look 20:30. Secondly how can i make the month appear as a number? September would be 09 .

Comment: Have you considered actually reading the documentation?

Comment: It crossed my mind. Thank you for the downvote.

Comment: If it makes you read the documentation next time it's well worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) has a nice table with the format specifiers you can use, follow up from that.

In this case, you should use `[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];` To get `09 02, 2012 20:30`

Answer (score 0):

Use capital [`H`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the hour and only two `M`'s for the month.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
```